FS3033: Multiple definition of element error
the xsd is too enormous and horrid to include (at least at this stage).
this is the full error
error FS3033: The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.XmlProvider' reported an error: Cannot read sample XSD from 'opendoc.xsd': System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: Multiple definition of element 'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0:text-properties' causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence. 
now I assume what its saying is, you cant have more than 1 definition of an element, presumable because when I read the xml, the mapping needs to be able to identify a unique type? (without getting involved in any complex rule validation).
That's understandable, the irony is though that I probably don't want to read any documents I want to construct them from scratch, in which case the mapping from element to type doent need to be unique.
(I've posted this on github too)
Any ideas how to avoid this issue?

...the xsd is too enormous and horrid to include... Is a [mre] not possible?

fair enough, I'll make a guess what the underlying issue is and try to replicate
